# Datastax OpsCenter 4.14 shows NO DATA in DASHBOARD

Tags: dashboard, datastax-enterprise, opscenter

My install of OpsCenter (version 4.1.4) shows NO DATA in DASHBOARD,
including  Cluster Reads & Writes, Cluster Latency, Disk IOPS. These graph always show no data, however, the graph of Storage Capacity can show used and free and total size.

My installing environments is described as follows:

system: centos 6

two machines:

```
192dot168dot58dot139  (opscenter installed) 
192dot168dot58dot137  (cassandra  2.0.6 installed,  datastax-agent installed)
```

my cassandra.yaml file:

```
seed_provider:   - seeds:  192dot168dot58dot137
listen_address: 192dot168dot58dot137
rpc_address: 0.0.0.0
```

then:

```
cd  opscenter_install_path/agent/bin
./setup  192dot168dot58dot139 192dot168dot58dot137 &
```

then generate the address.yaml file:
its'content is as follows:

`stomp_interface: "192dot168dot58dot139"`

then start datastax-agent

and I vistit 139ip:8888
and I choose Manage Existing Cluster
and enter 192dot168dot58dot137 and save Cluster

and then the above questions shows.

I tried another installing environments all in one machine 
192dot168dot58dot137  (cassandra 2.0.6 installed, opscenter installed, datastax-agent installed) 
all graph can show in DASHBOARD

Comment: Check /path/to/agent/log/agent.log for any errors connecting back to the opscenterd process.  You'll need to make sure port 61620 is accessible on that machine.  Also verify that the dashboard displays "All Agents Connected" and not "0 of 1 agents connected"

Comment: Did you ever fix this? I'm having the same exact problem with OpsCenter 5.0 and it only started after I upgraded from the 2.x series.